# nextflow - spltiCSV - each element - error : If you need to reuse the same component

Tags: groovy, nextflow

For a nextflow pipeline I'd like to read in a CSV file with five columns:

```
sample1,path/normal_R1.fastq,path/normal_R2.fastq,path/tumor_R1.fastq,path/tumor_R2.fastq
sample2,path/normal_R1.fastq,path/normal_R2.fastq,path/tumor_R1.fastq,path/tumor_R2.fastq
```

I read in the file, create a linkedHashMap. For each element I'd like to run few processes. The processes has been working fine without CSV iteration, as they were provided by a channel of tumor files and a channel of normal files.

When I edit the code with a CSV, I get error as:

> Process 'FASTP' has been already used -- If you need to reuse the same
> component, include it with a different name or include it in a
> different workflow context

Below is the code:

```
include { FASTP} from './fastp_process.nf'
include {bwa_index} from './index_process.nf'

include { align_bwa_mem} from './bwamem_process_already_index.nf'
include { gatk_markduplicates} from './gatk_markduplicates_process.nf'
include {setupnmdtags} from './setupnmdtags_process.nf'
include { recalibrate_bam } from './recalibratebam_process.nf'
include { applybqsr } from './applybqsr_process.nf'
include { mutect2 } from './mutect2_process.nf'
include { lancet } from './lancet_process.nf'
include { manta } from './manta_process.nf'
include { strelka } from './strelka_process.nf'
include { gatk_merge_vcfs } from  './gatk_merge_vcfs.nf'

workflow {
def csvFile = file("input_nextflow_files.csv")
def csvLines = csvFile.text.readLines()

def sampleMap = csvLines.collectEntries { line ->
    def lineCols = line.split(',')
    
    if (lineCols.size() >= 5) {
        def sampleName = lineCols[0]
        def normalR1 = file(lineCols[1])
        def normalR2 = file(lineCols[2])
        def tumorR1 = file(lineCols[3])
        def tumorR2 = file(lineCols[4])

        [(sampleName): [tuple(normalR1, normalR2), tuple(tumorR1, tumorR2)]]
    } else {
        return [:]
    }
}

sampleMap.each { sampleName, pairList ->
    def normalPair = pairList[0]
    def tumorPair = pairList[1]
    
    FASTP(tumorPair,normalPair,sampleName)
    align_bwa_mem(FASTP.out.reads_tumor,FASTP.out.reads_normal) //already_created index
    }
}
```

I believe it is something related to the FASTP process below (input):

```
process FASTP {
    maxForks 3
    debug true

    input:
    path(reads_tumor)  //val outdir  //doesn't work with path (outdir) // we pass multiple reads - for tumor and normal
    path(reads_normal)  //val outdir  //doesn't work with path (outdir)
    val (sample_name)

    output:

    tuple val(sample_name), path("${sample_id_tumor}_trim_{1,2}.fq.gz"), emit: reads_tumor
    path("${sample_id_tumor}.fastp.json"), emit: json_tumor
    path("${sample_id_tumor}.fastp.html"), emit: html_tumor
    
    tuple val(sample_id_normal), path("${sample_id_normal}_trim_{1,2}.fq.gz"), emit: reads_normal
    path("${sample_id_normal}.fastp.json"), emit: json_normal
    path("${sample_id_normal}.fastp.html"), emit: html_normal
    
    script:
    def (r1_normal, r2_normal) = reads_normal
    def (r1_tumor, r2_tumor)=reads_tumor

    """


ml fastp

    fastp  --in1 "${r1_normal}" --in2 "${r2_normal}" -q 20  -u 20 -l 40 --detect_adapter_for_pe --out1 "${sample_id_normal}_trim_1.fq.gz" --out2 "${sample_id_normal}_trim_2.fq.gz" --json "${sample_id_normal}.fastp.json" --html "${sample_id_normal}.fastp.html" --thread 12 
 
    fastp  --in1 "${r1_tumor}" --in2 "${r2_tumor}" -q 20  -u 20 -l 40 --detect_adapter_for_pe --out1 "${sample_id_tumor}_trim_1.fq.gz" --out2 "${sample_id_tumor}_trim_2.fq.gz" --json "${sample_id_tumor}.fastp.json" --html "${sample_id_tumor}.fastp.html" --thread 12 

echo "Exiting fastp"
 
   """
}
```

I do not know how to fix this error. I checked if multiple times I'm not including FASTP process it is fine. I remove include and FASTP calling process they didn't work. So I cannot figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through your sample map using `each`, you are effectively trying to re-use the *FASTP* and *align_bwa_mem* processes with each iteration. Nextflow just complains that if they (i.e. the processes) need to be re-used, they'll need to be included using a different name (i.e. using a [module alias](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-aliases)) or in a different workflow context (i.e. using a [sub-workflow](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#workflow)). A better way to achieve what you want is to use [channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html) and the [`splitCSV`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) operator, for example:

```
params.samples_csv = 'input_nextflow_files.csv'

include { FASTP } from './fastp_process.nf'


workflow {

    def header = ['sampleName', 'normalR1', 'normalR2', 'tumorR1', 'tumorR2']

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.samples_csv )
        .splitCsv( header: header )
        .multiMap { row ->
            
            def tumor_reads = tuple( file(row.tumorR1), file(row.tumorR2) )
            def normal_reads = tuple( file(row.normalR1), file(row.normalR2) )
            
            tumor:
                tuple( row.sampleName, tumor_reads )
            normal:
                tuple( row.sampleName, normal_reads )
        }
        .set { samples }


    FASTP( samples.tumor.mix( samples.normal ) )

    ...
}
```

Or if you wanted more flexibility, another way would be to import *FASTP* using a module alias:

```
params.samples_csv = 'input_nextflow_files.csv'

include { FASTP as FASTP_TUMOR } from './fastp_process.nf'
include { FASTP as FASTP_NORMAL } from './fastp_process.nf'


workflow {

    ...

    FASTP_TUMOR( samples.tumor )
    FASTP_NORMAL( samples.normal )

    ...
}
```

Contents of `./fastp_process.nf`:

```
process FASTP {

    tag { sample_id }

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads, stageAs: 'reads/*')

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_trim_{1,2}.fq.gz"), emit: reads
    path "${sample_id}.fastp.json", emit: json
    path "${sample_id}.fastp.html", emit: html

    script:
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    """
    fastp \\
        --in1 "${r1}" \\
        --in2 "${r2}" \\
        -q 20 \\
        -u 20 \\
        -l 40 \\
        --detect_adapter_for_pe \\
        --out1 "${sample_id}_trim_1.fq.gz" \\
        --out2 "${sample_id}_trim_2.fq.gz" \\
        --json "${sample_id}.fastp.json" \\
        --html "${sample_id}.fastp.html" \\
        --thread {task.cpus}
    """
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't have occurred to use multiMap. How do I learn or develop this? I'd have plainly worked with splitCSV channel.

Comment: The fastp command won't run as it is unable to find the files. Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Data print fine if I do: `samples.tumor.map{  it -> println(it) }` that is file and path are being read and stored properly. But what changes in the FASTP process?

Comment: If I do not use stageAs when I print r1 and r2 files in def (r1, r2) = reads they don't have complete path. But only normal_R1.fastq and normal_R2.fastq instead of `path/`normal_R1.fastq and `path/`normal_R2.fastq . How do I store complete file path with the file? I understand I can use `stageAs`

Comment: @DeathMetal By complete path, do you mean an _absolute_ path? Note that the [input `path` qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-path) will ensure the files are staged into the process execution directory for you. By default, Nextflow will create symlinks in these directories with absolute paths to the input files. To ensure your workflow is portable and reproducible, the objective should be to access the input files via the symlinks. With `stageAs` as above, `r1` and `r2` should be `reads/normal_R1.fastq` and `reads/normal_R2.fastq`, respectively.

Comment: @DeathMetal I can confirm that `fastp` will be able to find the files. There might be some other issue here. Please consider editing your question to include some code the reproduces the problem and I'll take a look, thanks!